# Custom View and ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

i have create my own View and ViewGroup. The ViewGroup is a LinearLayout that includes a dynamic TableView. I add two rows, but only one is displayed. The first Row take the full height.

The Destination on Run is this Output:

[image: output]

But i need this:

[image: Need this]

Perfectly, the cells are square and the Bottom is unused.
Like this:

[image: perfect]

I have uploaded the stylized [code](https://gist.github.com/1141875)

I hope someone can help me.

Sry, i cant include the images directly because: "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

And the image Urls i have included as text because: "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks."

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont know more about creating table by code but same problem i feel while creating the table from XMl file. In that time i have solved the problem by using height-width of linear layout with fill parent option. 
Or U can Use Relative Layout instead of the Linear Layout and try it. May be it helps u.

Comment: Now i have tried with LinearLayout as Row and i get the first solution (second image on my post)

Comment: Ok Nice. Now for third image, U have to set the buttomMargin of the Uper layer of the TableView. I mean take One LinearLayout which cover the whole Table layout and set the Bottom Margin of the Linear Layout. Then perhaps u can get the second solution of your third image.

Comment: Then i use a absolute design. But the layout must be scale automatic. Every cell must have a max uniform square size. If i modify the onMeasure to force size. The cells in another rows don´t have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the weights this way.

```
float rowWeight = 1/noOfColumns;
TableRow.LayoutParams mCellLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, rowWeight );
mCellLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

Comment: I get the same output like weight=1

Comment: Sorry. the weight should also be applied to celllayoutparams. Try above code.

Comment: Sry, nothing change to the first version.